# What is the difference between using a task for npm vs using a script in an Azure pipeline?

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm struggling to work out the differences between the two below snippets of an Azure pipeline when doing an npm install.

Snippet 1 (using task):

```yaml
- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'install'
```

Snippet 2 (using script):

```yaml
- script: npm install
```

My only guess is one is more performant than the other? Also, is one approach recommended over the other?

Answer (score 5):

Looking at [Npm@1 task source](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/NpmV1/), it doesn't do any particular magic, so the choice is rather a mater of personal preference.

One drawback of `Npm@1` task is that it **caches the output of `npm` command** - so if it's taking a long time, you won't see any progress or warnings in the logs, until npm is finished (which may take a considerable amount of time).