# Why is Azure DevOps' Npm command not showing any log until the task is done?

Tags: npm, azure-devops, tfs, azure-pipelines

We run an Azure DevOps (Server 2020 Update 1) instance in my company and use it to run the pipelines. When the tasks are running, there is no output until the task is done.

For example we run

```
  - task: Npm@1
    displayName: 'Run ng e2e tests'
    condition: eq('${{parameters.e2e}}', 'true')
    inputs:
      command: custom
      verbose: false
      customCommand: 'run e2e:ci'
```

which currently runs into issues, but I have to wait the whole task (around 10 minutes) to get any information. To my knowledge "verbose" is just for "--verbose" not the standard output.

Is there any way to enable the log output while running?

Comment: I may have found the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69565044/12550134

Comment: You could also try debug output on the pipeline to get a more detailed view, but I am not sure if this will trigger npm task to show detailed output. https://medium.com/@geralexgr/enable-debug-logs-on-azure-devops-pipelines-d815deede08f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I answered in my question, the log of the task is cached thus only showing when it is done. See: [What is the difference between using a task for npm vs using a script in an Azure pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69558470/what-is-the-difference-between-using-a-task-for-npm-vs-using-a-script-in-an-azur/69565044#69565044)